# quartz-core: Undo for a paint app in iOS

Tags: ios, paint, quartz-core

I create a paint app for iOS using the quartz-core framework, what should I do if I want to add the Undo function?

Here are some code fragment:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    [drawColor set];
    for (Line *line in linesCompleted) {
        [[line color] set];
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, [line begin].x, [line begin].y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, [line end].x, [line end].y);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/Articles/UndoManager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @TheMuffinMan, I got the solution, it's [UndoManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/Articles/UndoManager.html).